Does GitHub Service Containers usage count against Docker pull rate limits?
I’m using GitHub Service Containers to set up PostgreSQL in my GitHub Actions. Since the service containers pull Docker images and set them up in the runner machine, I want to confirm whether these pulls count against Docker’s rate limits.
Has anyone encountered issues with rate limits in this context, or does GitHub handle it differently? Any insights or documentation references would be appreciated.
Example Config:
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build & Analyse
    runs-on: ["self-hosted", "Linux"]
    env:
      ImageOS: ubuntu20
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test1234
          POSTGRES_DB: test
        ports: ["5432:5432"]
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5


You mean Docker Hub rate limits?

If you mean Docker Hub rate limits?
Then the answer is No, GitHub Actions handles Docker image pulls internally and doesn't directly count against your Docker Hub rate limit.
Because, GitHub Actions uses a shared pool of container images Pulls for
service containers are managed by GitHub's infrastructure These pulls
do NOT count against Docker Hub's rate limits
However, GitHub does handle some of this differently based on the type of runner and setup, so as you’re using self-hosted runners, the pull requests for Docker images count against the rate limits associated with your runner’s IP address. This can potentially lead to rate-limiting issues if you frequently run workflows that pull images. More specifically, image pulls are subject to Docker Hub's rate limits (100 pulls per 6 hours for unauthenticated users, and 200 pulls for authenticated users) unless you have a paid Docker subscription
Add your Docker credentials as GitHub secrets and log in to Docker Hub during the workflow
steps:
  - name: Log in to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

See More:

https://www.warpbuild.com/blog/rate-limits-self-hosted-runners#:~:text=cloud%20provider%27s%20support.-,Docker%20Hub,-Docker%20Hub%20enforces
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/use-cases-and-examples/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/#github-actions

